# "/activity" page, similar to "/reputation" page

Tags: feature-request, api, activity

It'd be nice to have a page at https://stackoverflow.com/activity that behaves similar to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

That is, a simple dump of all a user's activity (perhaps capped by default to the last 100 activities).  Currently, you can brute-force scrape it by just paging through your user profile page, but a simpler API would be useful, especially for badge-seekers like myself (could easily check for progress on Strunk & White and Copy Editor for example).  If it even had vote history on there as well, that would make it even more useful/powerful.

### Format

The same general format for `/reputation` could be leveraged even, something like:

```
-- 2011-01-23
1 1234567
4 5678901
1 4252624
-- 2011-01-24
2 4142441
3 4142441
1 4959666
```

Where the first column is simply an activity type (e.g., 1 = ask, 2 = answer, 3 = comment, 4 = vote up, ...), and the second column is the ID of the question/answer.

### Potential Issues

- One thing I'm not sure about is if you could capture votes on comments since I don't think those share the ID scheme that questions/answers do.
- I'm not sure if not exposing your own vote history in your activity is by design or not, so if it's intentionally excluded then it would likely need to be excluded here as well, and that would somewhat reduce the usefulness of this feature
- As mentioned above, the activity listing is going to be far greater for most folks than their reputation listing, though it's still something that can be paged through as-is so this may not be an issue anyway (if there's a cap on the number of activity pages, I'm unaware of it)